# Records not getting dispalyed properly in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

The below code is giving me the result but I am not able to display the second column using the same way.
Only the first column is getting rendered.
Please do let me know what syntax i am missing.

```
j$=jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function(){
  alert(JSON.stringify(result));
  var htmltable=j$('[id$="example"]').DataTable({'responsive': true,
                                                 "data": result,
                                                 "columns": [{"data": "Name",}],
                                                 "columnDefs":[{
                                                   "render": function(data, type, result){
                                                               return '<a href="/'+result.Id+'">'+result.Name+'</a>'
                                                             },"targets":0
                                                              }],                                           
                                                 "deferRender":  true
                                               });

  });
  }, 
  {escape: true}
);
```

Comment: casing issue? Are you sure its `Name` and not `name`?

Comment: No ..not the casing issue. I verified ,Its Name only. I am getting the names in the alert box.

Comment: Actually, in columns ,if I use columns: [
            { title: 'Name' }
deferRender :  true
          ]    the record names first letter is appearing on use with deferRender : true

Comment: It's rendering if you use that?

Comment: only the first letter

Comment: The code you posted is invalid. There are more closing brackets/parentheseses than opening ones.

Comment: Actually , those brackets are valid. have not posted the code which are  above the jquery.noConflict().

Comment: got the idea. realized the issue. i need to concatenate the letters of the name.first letter is coming in the first column,second letter iscoming in the second column,similarly for third

Comment: If you found a solution please answer your own question and mark it as resolved.

Comment: No.No actually there is still an issue....I am not able to display second column

Comment: Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Show us wider code excerpt and data sample, or, even better, working demo, showing what works as expected and what doesn't. It is hard to make guesses without necessary context.